# How can I set default (global) c_cpp include paths for VSCode when using WSL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have the following setting in my settings.json file:

```
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "/usr/include/**"
    ],
```

which I found details on [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp)

However when I have a WSL VSCode based window opened, this setting is grayed out and hovering over it states:

```
This setting cannot be applied in this window. It will be applied when you open a local window.
```

If I open a new window outside of WSL, this setting seems to apply correctly. I would like this setting to be active when using a VSCode window opened for WSL:Ubuntu but am struggling to find a way to do this.

Comment: Did you set this in your workspace or user level settings

Comment: @DanielA.White I set this in the User level settings (file -> preferences -> settings). I want this to be active globally in WSL VSCode windows, instead of having to add the same includes to every project's c_cpp_properties.json file